# Expected a value of type '() => dynamic', but got one of type 'IdentityMap<String, bool>'

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

i make meal app using flutter and local data from dummy data

link github project  https://github.com/rowanibrahem/meal.git

i want to make filters that user choose ingredients of meal and save it and make filteretion to the meals that have this ingredients only but this error I can't handled it

On main.dart

```dart
  void _setFilters(Map<String, bool> _filterData) {
    setState(() {
      _filters = _filterData;
      _availableMeals = DUMMY_MEALS.where((meal) {
        if (_filters['gluten']! && !meal.isGlutenFree) {
          return false;
        }
        if (_filters['lactose']! && !meal.isLactoseFree) {
          return false;
        }
        if (_filters['vegan']! && !meal.isVegan) {
          return false;
        }
        if (_filters['vegetarian']! && !meal.isVegetarian) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }).toList();
    });

  }

/// routes
  routes: {
       //...
        FiltersScreen.routeName: (context) =>
            FiltersScreen(_filters as Function() , _setFilters as Map<String, bool>),
      },
```

And on filter page

```dart
class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/filters';
   final Function() saveFilters;
   final Map<String , bool> currentFilters;

  FiltersScreen(this.saveFilters, this.currentFilters);

  @override
  State<FiltersScreen> createState() => _FiltersScreenState();
}
```

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead of code image

Comment: https://github.com/rowanibrahem/meal.git this link of github of the project

Comment: @روانابراهيم, that's not how Stack Overflow works. Please include a [mre] directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using positional argument, it can get confusing, a better practice will be using named argument on method. Now let's stick with your current coding style.

The `FiltersScreen` accept in this order

```dart
 FiltersScreen(this.saveFilters, this.currentFilters);
```

but here the parameters are passing in wrong order.

```dart
FiltersScreen.routeName: (context) =>
            FiltersScreen(_filters as Function() , _setFilters as Map<String, bool>),
```

Also you like to get the item from callback which will be

```dart
class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/filters';

  final Function(Map<String, bool> _filterData) saveFilters;
  final Map<String, bool> currentFilters;

  const FiltersScreen(this.saveFilters, this.currentFilters);

  @override
  State<FiltersScreen> createState() => _FiltersScreenState();
}
```

And on main.dart  route,

```dart
FiltersScreen.routeName: (context) =>
    FiltersScreen(_setFilters, _filters),
```